# Low resolution image blurred out in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I'm playing around with three.js to get more familiar with it however when I upload low resolution images (16x16px to be exact) as cube textures, they tend to blur out and look really fuzzy. I've tried looking on other posts and couldn't find a solution to unblur them that actually worked. here's an example of what's happening:

[demo](https://THREEjs.cooperbuch.repl.co)

[what it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Fyh7.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You should post some code otherwise it's tough to give you an exact fix for your problem.

That being said, I'm pretty sure the issue is with texture filtering. See the [Three.js texture filtering docs](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/textures/Texture). For your use case I think what you want is to set Texture.magFilter and Texture.minFilter to THREE.NearestFilter. That should give you the pixellated look you'd like.